# Handling Play/Pause click events in mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

I need to listen to play/pause click events.

```
media.addEventListener("pause", onPause);
media.addEventListener("play", onPlay);
```

using this causes me problems since in my code I sometimes need to call media.play() & media.pause() but I don't want the listener to execute. Listening only to clicks would solve my problem.

1. Is it possible to do or do I have to change the library code?
2. How would you recommend changing the library if its the only option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My method was to set a value inside the media's dataset before programmatically calling play() and pause(). Something like this:

```
media.addEventListener("pause", function(e) {
    if(media.dataset.calledByProgram === undefined || media.dataset.calledByProgram === false) {
        // whatever is in onPause()
    }
    media.dataset.calledByProgram = null;
}, false);
```

The `media.dataset.calledByProgram === false` test is in case you might have set it somewhere in your code.

So, before calling media.play(), just set `media.dataset.calledByProgram = true;`.

I have no idea if that's the best practice but it's worked for me.